# scrollview is not working while using google maps and tabs in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_bg_color"
    tools:context="com.example.vickey.medicalcompanies.DoctorInfo">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="title"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/speciality"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="spec"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbarlayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/doctor_map"
                    android:name="com.example.vickey.medicalcompanies.WorkaroundMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                   >

                </fragment>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/doctor_map"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#805A6051"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/review"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="1247 reviews"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                        android:isIndicator="false"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:scaleY="0.7"
                        android:scaleX="0.7"
                        android:rating="5"
                        android:stepSize="0.2"
                        android:theme="@style/RatingBar" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/doctor_map"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/lightGrey"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/layout_bg_color" />

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_ll2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_ll"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        android:background="@color/tab.location.bg"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color" />

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity file**

```
public class DoctorInfo extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    TabLayout tabLayout, tabLayout2;
    ViewPager viewPager, viewPager2;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    GoogleMap gMap = null;

    TextView title, specility;
    ScrollView scrollView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_info);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
        specility = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.speciality);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        title.setText("Dr. Regis Ketelers");
        specility.setText("Cardiologue");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

       /* SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.doctor_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
*/


            mMap = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.doctor_map)).getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview); //parent scrollview in xml, give your scrollview id value

            ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.doctor_map))
                    .setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTouch() {
                            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        }
                    });


//tab1
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        //tab2
        viewPager2 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);
        setupViewPager2(viewPager2);

        tabLayout2 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs2);
        tabLayout2.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2);

    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;


        LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21, 57);
        gMap.addMarker(new
                MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Tutorialspoint.com"));
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TutorialsPoint));

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new MapandDetails2(), "Services");
        adapter.addFragment(new MapandDetails2(), "Map & Details");
        adapter.addFragment(new MapandDetails2(), "Galery");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    private void setupViewPager2(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter2 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Location2Fragment(), "Location1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Location2Fragment(), "Location2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Location2Fragment(), "Location3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                Intent intent = new Intent(DoctorInfo.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DoctorInfo.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

}




//workAroundMapFragment class
public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
    enter code here

}
```

it is complete code of tabview and google maps and it is working fine without scrollview. scrollview is working in tabs but not in whole activity. i want to use scrollview in whole activity. but it is not working.
i tried some more solution but gain nothing.
i mention all the code:
Activity,
.xml file
and one require java class
 guide me please if anyone know.

Comment: I notice that the child `LinearLayout` of your `ScrollView` is using `match_parent` for its height. Doing this generally makes scrolling not work, because a `ScrollView` needs a child that is _taller_ than it in order to have anything to scroll.

Comment: i changed LinearLayout match_parent to wrap_parent. but it is not working